# Create Insert Trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

This is my code:

```
USE MyGuitarshop
GO

CREATE TRIGGER Products_INSERT
ON Products
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Products
    SET DateAdded = GETDATE()
    WHERE DateAdded IS NULL;
END;
GO

USE MyGuitarShop

INSERT INTO Products (CategoryID, ProductCode, ProductName, Description, ListPrice, DiscountPercent, DateAdded)
VALUES (1, '229985', 'Quartz Watch', 'Lovely watch with a quartz face', 29.99, 12, NULL);
GO

USE MyGuitarShop

SELECT * FROM Products
```

It pops this error: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Products_UPDATE, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 21]
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I don't understand the error or how to fix it. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: If we do your homework.. who are you going to get help from in the real world :)

Comment: I always wondered if teachers watched the SO boards after giving out homework assignments like this.

Comment: @marc_s - Apologies. I've added the correct tag.

Comment: @dfundako - my professor said we would have to research and use online resources for help. I've coded most of it myself, I've just run into a problem I can't figure out and am asking for help. I'm not asking anyone to do my homework for me, just to point me in the right direction to figure out why this isn't doing what it should.

Comment: @Krystianya this issue is what marc_s responded to. You need to use `IS NULL` not `= NULL`

Comment: Since your trigger doesn't reference the [`inserted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables) table, it will update _all_ rows where `DateAdded is NULL` (when fixed) rather than only the rows inserted by the statement that caused the trigger to fire. Not typical behavior for a trigger.

Comment: HABO answered the question correctly in his comment I think.

Comment: Perhaps if we could see the code for `Products_UPDATE` the error message would make more sense. The error ("Subquery returned more than 1 value.") has, in general, been addressed repeatedly on SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You **cannot** use the regular comparison operators with `NULL` - anything compared to `NULL` is undefined and therefore "false".

The only thing you can do to check with `NULL` is to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` :

```
UPDATE Products
SET DateAdded = GETDATE()
WHERE DateAdded IS NULL;
```

Comment: This is assuming there are no previous records in the table that were entered with a NULL DateAdded value, right?

Comment: @dfundako: as far as I understand the task given, this trigger is supposed to update *all* rows that have `DateAdded IS NULL` - regardless of whether those rows were just inserted, or already existed. So yes - this trigger updates *ALL* rows in the database table that have a `DateAdded` column with `NULL`

Comment: @marc_s Thank you so much! This code didn't work earlier, but I had to restart my computer (it was being difficult) and once I did and tried this code again it worked perfectly and all my rows of NULL in the date were filled in with today's date. Thank you so much for your time and your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Krystianya: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Comment: @marc_s Sorry. I'm new to stackoverflow, so I didn't know about clicking the checkmark. But I've done so now. I had clicked the up arrow because that's what I thought I was supposed to do. I'm sorry for the oversight. Thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @Krystianya: that's ok - now you've learned about it, and use it already - just keep using it on your next questions, too! :-)

Answer (score -3):

Try

`UPDATE inserted SET DateAdded = GETDATE() WHERE DateAdded IS NULL; END;`

Comment: Your where predicate will NEVER evaluate to true because nothing ever equals NULL.

Comment: You're correct. I wrote that in a hurry. I've edited my answer.